# Should the link on What should I do when someone answers my question? not point to page in helpcenter

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, hyperlinks, help-center

The link [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page in the help-center points to an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) page on meta.

Should the hyperlink not point to the page [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in the help-center.

As far as I know should the help-center replace/consolidate the many [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) pages.

Comment: The Help Center replaces only the "official" /faq that used to be on each site. Most questions marked [meta-tag:faq] are not official and were written and are maintained by ordinary community members, not Stack Exchange employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated it to link to the Help Center page about accepted answers, but there's also still a link to the MSO post. The MSO post goes into greater detail about the mechanics and some of the reasoning behind the system's rules, so it's there for the indefatigable that truly want to know everything there is to know on the subject. :)